# React JSX append HTML (react object) after initialization

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

How do I make this function work, appending to my react object between initialization and return

```
render () {
    var users = this.state.users,
        appContainer = <div id="container"></div>

    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        // this doesn't work
        appContainer.appendChild(this.createCard(users[i]));
    }

    return appContainer;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use HTML and escape React, just use a `ref` which is like a persistent DOM node across renders. I'm unsure how often or if you would have to re-append DOM nodes after a legitimate render/update.

---

The best pattern is to get as close to a PureComponent as possible. A PureComponent renders HTML purely off props -- no update lifecycle logic.

In the future, internal state will be considered an anti-pattern (separation of model and view allows for data handoff between platforms/devices, and for different skins to render the same stuff).

```
render () {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      {this.userCards()}
    </div>
  );
}

userCards () {
  if (this.props.users) {
    return this.props.users.map(user => this.userCard(user));
  }
}

userCard (user) {
  if (user) {
    return (
      // React may complain to use key={user.id} for tracking and mutating items
      <div className='card'>
        {user.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Some people prefer `userCardsTemplate()`, `userCardsUI()`, `renderUserCards()` etc

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for misreading the question. What you're looking to do can be achieved with the "portals" pattern described by Ryan Florence & Michael Jackson [here](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md). Below is an attempt at solving what I believe is your question. Forgive me if I'm still not understanding your question.

```
render() {
  // dont render anything, open a "portal"
  return <div ref="container" />;
}

componentDidMount() {
  // get initialized component markup
  var container = this.refs.container;
  var cards = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    cards.push(this.createCard(users[i]));
  }

  // start a new React render tree with the container and the cards
  // passed in from above, this is the other side of the portal.
  ReactDOM.render(<div>{cards}</div>, container):
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Oddly, taking out the <div> tags from ReactDOM.render() caused a crash for me, like so: ReactDOM.render({cards}, container)

Comment: That's probably because the cards array has a list of components, while react needs a single top level component. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn#writing-markup-with-jsx

Answer (score 7):

do something like this

```
render () {
var users = this.state.users,
var usersDiv = [];
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var temp = (<div>{users[i]}</div>);
    usersDiv.push(temp);
}
return(
  <div>
     {usersDiv}
  </div>)
}
```

this would return you a div with multiple users div based on your JSON.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution and works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Put your children into a normal array and then use `{}` to put that array inside your div element (i.e. create the div element after the array). That keeps it immutable. Adding children to it afterwards seems very un-React-y to me.

Comment: As far as I've understood, JSX elements are supposed to be immutable. I.e. it's OK to put in dynamically created things at creation time, but "appending" to an existing element is a no-no. Given that it's Javascript there is probably a hack to do it, but I don't think it's part of the supported API.